# Como sobrescrever CSS do PrimeFaces adicionado via Maven?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Estou usando MegaMenu no meu projeto, mas as opções dele são bem maiores que a largura das colunas deste componente, por isso as opções do menu ultrapassam a área destinadas à elas, o que fica bem feio.

Adicionei o primefaces via Maven. Como faço pra alterar o CSS do MegaMenu para que as colunas sejam mais largas, alterar cores, etc?

Ou se não precisar alterar o CSS, como faço?

Answer (score 3):

Basta declarar a folha de estilo que contém o que precisa sobrescrever depois de carregado o do primefaces. Como o do primefaces estará em `<head />`, pode declarar assim:

```xml
<h:head>
    <!-- normal aqui -->
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="sua-folha-de-estilos.css" />
    <!-- segue o corpo da sua página -->
</h:body>
```

Outra forma é utilizar `styleClass` para configurar classe(s) com o estilo customizado, `style` para o CSS e por aí vai.

Dependendo pode ser necessário "forçar" que o seu estilo seja aplicado e não o do primefaces, então em último caso você pode usar `!important`, mas antes veja como funciona a [precedência](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) de estilos.